# Is there a way to change order of the key in a hashtable?

Tags: sorting, hash-tables

Say i have following keys in hashtable:

```
"first1"
"second2"
"third3"
"forth4"
```

Is there a way to put key `"third3"` at the top. So that when i run func `hash-table-keys` i get following list:

```
("third3" "first1" "second2" "forth4")
```

I tried running `remhash` followed by `puthash`. But the order stays the same.

Comment: Hash table doesn't have order by definition.

Answer (score 3):

*No*, you cannot change the order of the keys in a hash table.

As @xuchunyang's comment points out, hash tables do not have an
order in the way you're thinking about them.   From the elisp manual node
on
[hash tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html):

```
The correspondences in a hash table are in no particular order.
```

You may wish to order the keys in some form (say, for the purposes
of accessing the values in some particular order), but that ordering
will live outside the hash table itself.  `hash-table-keys`
returns a *list* of the table's keys, and you can manipulate that
list just as any other list: `sort`ing it, `setf`ing it, and so on.